# Reduce number of redirects during Paypal checkout

Tags: paypal

The current scenario is:

1. (my site/app) User clicks Paypal Pay now
2. (PayPal) Then next page Clicks on Pay through Credit card/Debit Card
3. (PayPal) Next page enters card information
4. (PayPal) Next page is the review page
5. (my site/app) Next page is the confirmation page

I want to reduce this many number of pages. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the user's cookies / past history using PayPal, step (3) might already be expanded for them (effectively skipping #2).

Are you using a PayPal API? Do you have a review page on your site after the order is approved on PayPal? If so you can skip that and proceed to immediately capture the payment when the user returns from PayPal.  There is a parameter, `&useraction=commit` in Classic APIs redirects, or the equivalent API context / payment experience parameter in REST APIs, which will change the verbiage of the final button the user clicks within PayPal, so that they know that action will lead to a return that results in an immediate capture/execute.